# jQuery filidownload - в failCallback не приходит ошибка из Asp Web Api метода

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, jquery-file-upload

На стороне сервера срабатывает `catch` блок. Это правильно, ожидаемый результат:

```
try 
{
//...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
var errorResponse = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
                    "Ошибка получения данных");

errorResponse.Content = new StringContent("error: " + ex.ToString());
                return errorResponse;
}
```

На клиенте серверный код, что написан выше, вызывается отсюда:

```
$.fileDownload(_url, {
                        successCallback: function (url) { },
                        failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
                            debugger;
                            alert(responseHtml);
                        }
                    });
```

`failCallback` отрабатывает, но в `responseHtml` пусто. Ожидалось, что там будет текст ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как отправлять текст ошибки через responseHtml failCallback-а выяснить не удалось.
Как вариант решения - на сервере в cookie записываю текст ошибки, а на UI читаю его через
$.cookie("имя куки") в теле failCallback. После чего удаляю куку с ошибкой - $.removeCookie('кука', { path: '/' });